# Reversed Search Terms in MongoDB - Database Containing Keywords

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

For my situation, my search terms and database entries are reversed. I have a database containing keywords (typically 1 or 2 words) and I have strings (typically 3-5 words) that I want to compare with my database entries.

For example, here are two documents (of tens of thousands) that are saved in a collection in the database:

```
{ _id: 1, keyword: "John Smith" },
{ _id: 2, keyword: "Apple" }
```

Then, I have the following strings:

```
"John Smith wins the award",
"Apple.com",
"Apple Keynote Presentation"
```

As you can see, my search terms and database entries are reversed. I want to search the database to find whether there is a document that has a "keyword" property that is contained in my string. Note: I'm dealing with the strings (like "Apple.com") one at a time and provided more than one for illustration purposes only.

I could take all of my documents out of the database and see if the string contains the keyword by looping through each keyword, but for performance reasons it would be better to find a match querying them in the database, if possible.

Is there a way to check if a string contains the keyword without taking the keywords out of the database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can achieve it easily with a text index. simply add a text index to your collection like this:

```
db.collection.createIndex({ keyword: "text" })
```

and then issue a text search command like this:

```
db.collection.find({ $text: { $search: 'John Smith wins the award' } })
```

[this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/text/index.html) explains how it works.